# Find all irreducible representations of a given group

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory

Suppose I want to find all irreducible representations of the group $\mathbb{Z}_n \oplus \mathbb{Z}_n$. So we want to find all homomorphisms $\pi: \mathbb{Z}_n \oplus \mathbb{Z}_n \to GL(V)$ where

> $GL(V) = \{T: V \to V \, \big| \, T$ is invertible $\}$

We utilize a few facts:

$(1)$ If $\pi$ is an irreducible representation of a (finite) **abelian** group $G$, then $\dim(V)=1$.

$(2)$ The number of conjugacy classes of a group $G$ is equal to the number of irreducible representations of $G$.

Using $(1)$, since $\mathbb{Z}_n \oplus \mathbb{Z}_n$ is abelian under addition, the irreducible representations $\pi$ must have $\dim(V) = 1$, i.e. $GL(V) \cong \mathbb{C}^\times$.

Using $(2)$, since $\mathbb{Z}_n \oplus \mathbb{Z}_n$ is abelian, then the number of conjugacy classes is equal to $|\mathbb{Z}_n \oplus \mathbb{Z}_n| = n^2$. Moreover, this tells us that there are $n^2$ representations.

So my question: how do we "find" representations of $\mathbb{Z}_n \oplus \mathbb{Z}_n$? We know that these mapping must be homomorphisms which map elements of $\mathbb{Z}_n \to \mathbb{Z}_n$ to $\mathbb{C}^\times$, but what is the exact mapping? Does the mapping matter? For example, can I say the collection of representations is

$$\{\pi(a,b)\} \hspace{1cm} \pi(a,b) = (-1)^{a+b} \hspace{0.3cm} a,b \in \mathbb{Z}_n \hspace{0.3cm}?$$

which you can check is a homomorphism. I suppose I'm not exactly understanding what exactly determines the mapping, since this is the only missing piece of information that we need (or so I assume).

Comment: It looks like you've only written down one representation $\pi:  \mathbb Z_n \oplus \mathbb Z_n \to \mathbb C^{\times}$--and even that is only well-defined if $n$ is even.

Comment: I'd suggest first thinking about representations of $\mathbb Z_n$.  What homomorphisms $\mathbb Z_n \to \mathbb C^{\times}$ are there?  How do you specify one of them?

Comment: @RaviFernando I understand that by design in $\mathbb{Z}_n$, we must have $\phi(0) = 1$, so that identities map to identities. Then $\phi$ is determined by our choice of $\phi(1)$. The question becomes, how do we abstract this to $\mathbb{Z}_n \oplus \mathbb{Z}_n$? Does $\phi$ become determined by $(1,1)$, since $|(1,1)| = |1| = n$?

Comment: It's not determined by the image of $(1, 1)$ alone, because $(1, 1)$ doesn't generate $\mathbb Z_n \oplus \mathbb Z_n$.  (For example, $\phi(1, 1)$ doesn't determine $\phi(1, 0)$.)  You'll need to choose a generating set.  Also:  in the case of $\mathbb Z_n$, I agree that $\phi$ is determined by $\phi(1)$, but what values can this take?  (There should be exactly $n$, for the reasons you explained in the question.)

Comment: @RaviFernando hmm I see what you mean, namely that $(1,1)$ does not generate $\mathbb{Z}_2$. So should the generating set be $\{(1,0), (0,1)\}$, as in a component-wise manner?

Comment: Yep!  And what elements of $\mathbb C^{\times}$ can they map to?

Comment: @RaviFernando hmm it's not immediately obvious to me what they should map to. I would just assume that we should have $\pi(1,0)^n = 1$ and $\pi(0,1)^n = 1$ in the same manner in $\mathbb{Z}_n$ that  $\phi(1)^n = 1$. But to tell you what $(1,0) \mapsto (?)$  or $(0,1) \mapsto (?)$ is beyond me

Comment: Yes, that's right--they can map to any elements $z_1, z_2 \in \mathbb C^{\times}$ such that $z_1^n = z_2^n = 1$.  Do you see why this gives the right number of possibilities?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, if $G, H, K$ are abelian groups, then there is a natural identification

$$\operatorname{Hom}_{\textrm{group}}(G\times H, K) = \operatorname{Hom}_{\textrm{group}}(G,K) \times \operatorname{Hom}_{\textrm{group}}(H,K)$$

Therefore, the problem becomes to find all homomorphisms $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z \rightarrow \mathbb C^{\ast}$.  Such a homomorphism is completely determined by where it sends the class of $1$.